# use a parser generator or hand-code when the file to parse is written by a program?

Tags: c, parsing, configuration-files

I'm aware of that this question is very generic and therefore difficult to answer.

I need to parse a text file with content similar to a configuration file. It contains descriptions of measureable signals, how to convert to physical units, comments, descriptions etc. If this file was written by a human I would use a parser generator such as lex/yacc or ANTLR. But since this file is written by an other program it is always correctly formatted etc.

Should I use a parser generator anyway, or is the fact that the file is written by an other program reason for writing a different kind of parser by hand-coding?

Comment: I would say it depends on the syntax you want to parse. If it is really simple and not recursive then writing a parser by hand instead of using a parser generator is perfectly fine.

Comment: Change the other program, to write out `xml` instead :)

Comment: You deserve a lart for mentioning XML.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't solve a problem which has been already solved
2. If you have tools to do your work for you, then use the tools. So if you can use either ANTLR or LEX/YACC then just go ahead and use that instead of hand coding a lexer and a parser.

It will be much less work

Source: [The Art of Unix Programming - By Eric S. Raymond](http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/)

Comment: As an aside, LEX/YACC are easier to understand and use than rolling your own. Every time.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds complex enough to me, save yourself the time and trouble and use lex/yacc, it doesn't matter if the file is generated by a program it just means you don't have to verify it when parsing, but you get that for free anyway if you use lex/yacc. Plus, changes to the format will be easier to deal with if you use a generator.